# locales -- weird behaviour --

Tags: thunderbird, locale

Thunderbird calendar shows time in US (non-24h) format.
After searching the WWW found out that it uses the locales settings.

checked locales settings and they all are on `nl_BE` and should thus give a 24-hour time format.

When launching a terminal this is what is showed.
  The locale command shows `LC_TIME` as `en_US` but the `localectl` command shows it, as it is set globally, as `nl_BE`.

Somebody any idea what is going on?

See screenshot below

[image: Terminal screenshot]
Thanks

Comment: Deduction would say : ThunderBird is based on `LC_TIME`

Comment: Future reviewers (or defossez), I transcribed the screenshot but I can't edit it now. Please feel free to use it in an [edit]. Transcript: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wzHX2ccHKv/

Comment: You must have set `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` somewhere. The best solution is that you figure out where that setting was done and change it.